# INSERT a record in a Local SQL Server database and app.config

Tags: sql-server, app-config, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to insert a record into the `Users` table with the C# code below. This is a Windows Forms project with `app.config` and the the records don't seem to be added to the database as intended. Any idea why?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DemoDBConnection
{
   public partial class RegisterUser : Form
   {
       SqlConnection connection = 
          new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
              ["DemoDBConnection"].ConnectionString);

       public RegisterUser()
       {
          InitializeComponent();
       }

       public void AuthenticateUser()
       {
           try
           {
               string insertQuery = 
                    "INSERT INTO Users (Username,Password) VALUES ('" +
                       this.txtUsername.Text + "','" + 
                       this.txtPassword.Text + "')";

               SqlCommand sqc = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, connection);

               connection.Open();
               sqc.ExecuteNonQuery();
               connection.Close();

               MessageBox.Show("Record Added Successfully");
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
                MessageBox.Show("Record Can Not Successfully" + ex.Message);
           }
    }

    private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AuthenticateUser();
    }
}
```

My `app.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DemoDBConnection"
             connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\App_Data\DemoDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
     </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What's the error message?  Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.  Put keywords in brackets.

Comment: do you get any error message ? what are your findings from debugging ?

Comment: You need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. This is a textbook example of sql injection.

Comment: And you really should not be storing passwords in plain text. They should be salted and hashed. Plain text passwords is a major no no.

Comment: @LarsTech  I don't get any error message at the moment the program runs but no records are added into the table.

Comment: @GuidoG I get no error message at all

Comment: @SeanLange no doubt I will do so but currently just wanted to see this working in order to continue

Comment: Has anyone of you guys tried to run the code on your side to see what I mean?

Comment: You are looking at the wrong database.  When you run your program, you are most likely looking at a *copy* of the database.  Look at your settings that use the DataDirectory.  It trips up a lot of programmers.  Also, ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows affected, so if it's equal to 1, your query worked.  But you still have to change your query to use parameters — always, always always.